# lightning: input field level validation help needed

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I need help validating " First Name" input field. The validation is the field should not accept numbers and special characters. There is no button at this point . But message should pop as user tries to enter data with numbers and special characters.In other words it should only accept characters.

can someone send me the snipplet [image: firstname validation]

Answer (score 1):

You just need to specify a pattern:

```
<lightning:input ... pattern="[a-zA-Z]*" 
                 messageWhenPatternMismatch="Please use only letters." />
```

If you're not familiar with regular expressions, you can read about them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) (or other resources).